# AngularJS ui.router replace $state.params in string

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I'm doing some kind of custom menu, we are using AngularJS v1.6.7, and ui.router, my state looks like:

```
.state('programs',
    {
        url: '/programs/:id',
        component: 'programs',
        //below is our custom menu object
        menu: {
            name: 'Program id :id'
        }
    })
```

So, I go to this state in HTML by `ui-sref="programs({id: '123'})"`. After that, somewhere in the code I fetch current state using `let currentState = $state.current`, then I try to display name like `currentState.menu.name` as the result I see `Program id :id`, my question is, how do I replace 'id' parameter in this string? Is there any public, ui.router out of the box method, to do this? ui.router somehow populates for example URL with these parameters, so in URL, I see 123 instead of :id. My `$state.params` holds id field: `{#:null, id:123}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the URL parameters by using the `resolve` method, which then will be available in your Controller and scope:

```
  {
      url: '/programs/:id',
      component: 'programs',
      menuData: function($stateParams){
          return {
            id: $stateParams.id
          }
      },
      controller: function($scope, menuData){
        // Now you can use it, either in a template, etc.
        $scope.id = menuData.id
      }
  })
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) out for more detailed steps